# Why MyBatis does not recognise Arrays.asList()?

Tags: java, arrays, mybatis

I have the following SQL code written in MyBatis:

```
    <select id="getItems" resultMap="someMap">
        SELECT *
        FROM my_table
        WHERE item_id = #{itemID}
        AND source_id IN
        <foreach item="sourceID" index="index" collection="sourceIDList"
            open="(" separator="," close=")">
              #{sourceID}
        </foreach>
    </select>
```

The corresponding mapper class in Java is:

```
public interface ItemMapper
{
    List<ItemDO> getItems(
        @Param("itemID") String itemID,
        @Param("sourceIDList") List<String> sourceIDList);
}
```

---

Now, in the caller class, if I am creating the List through Arrays.asList(), MyBatis is not able to map the parameters properly *(though, no exception is thrown)*:

```
List<String> sourceIDList = Arrays.asList("US", "UK");
```

But, if I'm creating the list through Constructor, everything works fine:

```
List<String> sourceIDList = new ArrayList<>();
sourceIDList.add("US");
sourceIDList.add("UK");
```

---

In the logs I can see for the case of Array.asList():

```
Parameters: Item1(String), US, UK(String)
```

Whereas, for the second case, it is like:

```
Parameters: Item1(String), US(String), UK(String)
```

---

I know that the corresponding object created by `Arrays.asList()` is not of the `java.util.ArrayList` class. But, I am curious why MyBatis wants that particular format?

Comment: Are you 100% certain you haven't written `Arrays.asList("US, UK")`?

Comment: `Arrays.asList(..)` can't be expanded.